# Bash unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: android, linux, bash, raspberry-pi4, chroot

I'm using a raspberry pi 4 with android 10 image on it, and I have an android app in Kotlin language which has to run some bash commands that load a linux image onto a loop device and then at the end, start ssh using chroot

this is the command that gives me the error:

```
/system/xbin/su root chroot /data/chroot bin/bash -c 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" && /etc/init.d/ssh start'
```

and this is the error message that i get:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
        PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Important note is that the same exact command runs fine and without any syntax errors on Asus Tinker board with android 6.0

Comment: What's the current value of $PATH?

Comment: PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin